# Authentication Error 499 using ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, error-499

Using the ArcGIS API for Python, when I create my GIS object:

```
gis = GIS(config["agol"]["agol_gis_url"], config["agol"]["agol_gis_user"], config["agol"]["agol_gis_pass"])
```

I can verify that it connects by checking if I have a token:

```
token = gis._con.token
print(token)
```

But If I try to create a FeatureLayer and search, I get an authentication error (499):

```
p = FeatureLayer(config["agol"]["resource_locs_fs_url"])
result = gis.content.search("id:{0}".format(p.properties.serviceItemId))

Error running result = gis.content.search("id:{0}".format(p.properties.serviceItemId)) in 'C:\test\main.py'. Message: (Error Code: 499)
```

If I go into ArcGIS Online and share the item to Everyone, the code works fine.  However, the item needs to be secured, so that is not an option.  Shouldn't my gis object grant me access to the item?

Comment: I just ran into this with my internal Portal - beating my head against my desk. Came upon this question which made me realize that neither my feature layer nor the map image layer was shared. D'OH! Make sure your item is shared, people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item was not shared as previously assumed.  Once sharing properties were updated, the item was in the search results.